# xcode beta 6 sprite kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6-beta6

I just update to xCode beta 6. In beta5 everything works but in beta 6 got to change somethings. I add a lot of "!" in my codes. Anyway, My project is little game. And after complete the level(won or lose) I want to call skscene.

The code is where in mainviewController:

```
if(flag==true){//  IF we WON
            /* That below lines should call "Won.swift" file But it doesn't */
            var scene = Won(fileNamed: "GameScene")
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            scene.position = CGPointMake(0, 568)
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Won.swift file is:

```
class Won: SKScene {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Fireworks", ofType: "mp3")!)

        // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound2, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "You Win";
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

}
```

this code does work in beta 5 but doesn't in beta6. 
Additionally I re-add uikit, avfoundation, spritekit foundations to project. And also check media files "mp3" or images are exist in bundle resources... The project runs perfectly without any eroor or warnings. But Skscene section doesn't work. I also tried to put breakpoint to trace how it does goes. the process goes on these lines but never goes "Won.swift" file.

Any suggestion? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *sounds* like your variable "flag" isn't being properly set to true.  Have you tried putting some println()'s in that code to see whether that code is actually being called?

Also, why are you putting it in the mainViewController?  Put it in the play scene, so that the scene is controlling when you move to a different scene.  Your main view controller should (probably) only fire up the very first scene, and let the scene logic handle transitioning to other scenes.

In fact, that could be your problem - if that "flag" is set to true, and that function is called repeatedly, say, every frame, then that file is getting called up repeatedly.  Or, if you're setting flag back to false in there, and that code gets executed, somewhere else, it might be calling your other scene file, and immediately switching back to it so that you never see the "Won" scene.

Could be a lot of things.  Start sprinkling some println() and set breakpoints to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: Problem solved with creating new project and Added resources to new project. :/ I hate betas.. :) thank you for reply